# MapReduce: Group results of Reducer into chunks of fixed size

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, output, reduce, reducers

I am using Map Reduce framework.

Let's say this is the input list `[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P ,Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z]`
 and my Mapper produces the following output:

```
<"Key 1" : A>
<"Key 2" : B>
<"Key 3" : C>
<"Key 1" : D>
<"Key 2" : E>
<"Key 3" : F>
<"Key 1" : G>
<"Key 2" : H>
<"Key 3" : I>
<"Key 1" : J>
<"Key 2" : K>
<"Key 3" : L>
<"Key 1" : M>
<"Key 2" : N>
<"Key 3" : O>
<"Key 1" : P>
<"Key 2" : Q>
<"Key 3" : R>
<"Key 1" : S>
<"Key 2" : T>
<"Key 3" : U>
<"Key 1" : V>
<"Key 2" : W>
<"Key 3" : X>
<"Key 1" : Y>
<"Key 2" : Z>
```

Now the Reducer output will normally be something like this:

```
<"Key 1" : A, D, G, J, M, P, S, V, Y>
<"Key 2" : B, E, H, K, N, Q, T, W, Z>
<"Key 3" : C, F, I, L, O, R, U, X>
```

But what I want to do is something like this:

I want to club the output for each key into chunks of 3 and then produce the final Reducer output.

So I want my Reducer output to look something like this:

```
<"Key 1" : [A, D, G], [J, M, P], [S, V, Y]>
<"Key 2" : [B, E, H], [K, N, Q], [T, W, Z]>
<"Key 3" : [C, F, I], [L, O, R], [U, X]>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated since I am stuck on this issue since two days. I am not able to figure out the last part i.e. how to group the output into chunks of 3.

**P.S.** If the chunk size is less than 3 (like in the example for the last key) then it's fine but it should not exceed 3.

Comment: Not sure, what do you mean by chunk of 3? You are already getting the data against each key in reducer, you can output it whatever way you wish.  Is this chunk going to be an ArrayList, or you just need this to be formatted output with `[]`

Comment: @gyan There is an underlying application, let's say it sends out a message to the users in a batch size of 3, which will consume the output of the Reducer. 

Now the result from Reducer is stored in certain file and the underlying application picks one output from the file and processes it.

So giving an example:

The application can process only 3 IDs at a time, so we directly provide the      output in chunk of 3. So when the application picks one output it can process it directly.

Comment: Ok.. So If I understand it correctly.. You need output like Line 1 - Key1: A,D,G  ; Line 2 - Key1:J,M,P . i.e. even though data belong to same key, it should come max in the chunk of 3 for each line. If so, kindly add the correct format in the query.

Comment: @gyan Yes exactly! That is the way I want the output! Can you please help me?

Comment: Thanks Namra, I have tried to put a simple solution for your case; which should not change your program much. You can keep using `Text` as output value type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, it is simple to do:

1. In your reducer, just take 3 values at a time into a for loop.
2. Concatenate these three with a delimiter of your choice and write to context

   context.write(Key, Value)

> Please note that you can write to context as many time you wish, i.e.
>   for each chunk of 3 output simply write to context and then take next
>   set of 3 values.

Please let me know if you find any difficulty.

A more sophisticated solution could be using [MultiOutputs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html). You can even write to different files using this.

A very good example is [here](http://www.lichun.cc/blog/2013/11/how-to-use-hadoop-multipleoutputs/) using hadoop 1.0.2

Below is the example taken from javadocs:

```
Usage in Reducer:

 <K, V> String generateFileName(K k, V v) {
   return k.toString() + "_" + v.toString();
 }

 public class MOReduce extends
   Reducer<WritableComparable, Writable,WritableComparable, Writable> {
 private MultipleOutputs mos;
 public void setup(Context context) {
 ...
 mos = new MultipleOutputs(context);
 }

 public void reduce(WritableComparable key, Iterator<Writable> values,
 Context context)
 throws IOException {
 ...
 mos.write("text", , key, new Text("Hello"));
 mos.write("seq", LongWritable(1), new Text("Bye"), "seq_a");
 mos.write("seq", LongWritable(2), key, new Text("Chau"), "seq_b");
 mos.write(key, new Text("value"), generateFileName(key, new Text("value")));
 ...
 }

 public void cleanup(Context) throws IOException {
 mos.close();
 ...
 }

 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) The `for` loop solution worked for me perfectly! Never thought the solution would turn out this simple!!

Didn't know that we could write to `context` multiple times. Thanks for that too! :) 

Didn't try the other approach, so can't tell about it's correctness.

Comment: But be careful when writing multiple times on context, writing to context is a heavy weight process and has potential to trigger speculative execution within cluster. In complex situation MultiOutputs is the optimized solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could write the values as fixed-sized chunks using the [ArrayWritable](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/ArrayWritable.html)  as your reducer value class in your case.

What you could do is,

- maintain an instance array list variable with fixed size 3 in your
  reducer class.
- In your reduce(), Iterate through the list of values of a given key, 
  and add it to the array list.
- If the size of the array list reaches 3, then just convert it to the
  ArrayWritable instance and pass it to the write() with key and then reset 
  the array list.
- Declare the outformat value class as ArrayWritable in your job
  config.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but the solution given below by @gyan worked for me! Using the `for` loop worked for me.

Comment: cool, glad to hear...pls dont forget to tick best answer/upvote for @gyan's answer ..